# Only LIMIT rows with specific number

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the title, As I'm not that experienced I had a real hard time trying to come up with a proper title.

So I have this query to fetch all the comments of a specific topic.
Now for my paging I want to limit it down to 20 rows, but ONLY for posts with pid (parent_id) zero.

```
SELECT *, c.id AS cid, u.id AS userid 
FROM comments c 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = c.uid 
WHERE c.tid = :id ORDER BY c.posted ASC LIMIT 20
```

How do I go about limiting the posts by 20 WHERE pid = 0 without removing every row with pid = 1?

If I add:

```
 WHERE c.tid = :id AND c.pid = 0
```

I'll just get all comments without a pid.

So, for example, it shows 100 comments, but only 20 that has `pid = 0` in the database. That's what I want.

Comment: i really cant understand what do you want. you say `without removing every row with pid = 1?` then you say `but only 20 that has pid = 0 in the database. That's what I want.` ????

Comment: `SELECT *, c.id...`??? Why are you selecting some columns twice?

Comment: @Strawberry maybe his processing code works with the alias names he is setting... or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be possible to use a union to fetch the two sets here:

```
SELECT *, c.id AS cid, u.id AS userid 
FROM comments c 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = c.uid 
WHERE c.tid = :id 
AND pid != 0
ORDER BY c.posted ASC
LIMIT // whatever limit you want here
UNION
SELECT *, c.id AS cid, u.id AS userid 
FROM comments c 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = c.uid 
WHERE c.tid = :id 
AND pid = 0
ORDER BY c.posted ASC
LIMIT 20
```